# Connect tables with or without records

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.0

I have two tables like `units` and `price`. Units table fields are `unit1`, `unit2`. `Price` table fields are `id`, `rateper`, `price`. Now i want connect those two tables like the `Price` table `rateper <=0` or `Price table is empty` then return  `unit1` else `rateper`. i wrote query like below but that not wroking

```
 select case when rateper <=0  then unit1 else rateper from units,price
```

am using `postgresql` version 9.0

Units Table

```
+------+-----+
|Unit1 |Unit2|
--------------
| 2    | 10  |
| 1    | 20  |
+------+------
```

Price Table

```
+------+-------------+---------+
|id    + rate per    + price   |
--------------------------------
|1     |0            | 100     |
|2     |1            | 200     |
|3     |2            | 300     |
--------------------------------

Result :

2
1
3
```

If Price table does not have rows then show Result is

```
2
1
```

Comment: Wild stab in the dark: You want a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. +1 for including your version and making some effort; thanks for listening to my prior suggestions.

Comment: @CraigRinger thanks sir but i have one doubt those columns are not having a foreign key.

Comment: You can join on any condition that returns a boolean result. You need *some* way to connect the two tables together, but it doesn't have to be based on primary/foreign key relationships. You haven't shown the tables, the data, the expected results, or explained how you want to link the two tables together, so it's kind of hard to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to specify columns on which you want to join these tables

```
select
    case
        when p.rateper <= 0 or p.rateper is null then u.unit1
        else p.rateper
    end
from units as u
    full outer join price as p on p.id = u.???
```

**update** I think you need some kind of full outer join. I'm still doesn't completely understand what exactly you want, but try this query:

```
select
    coalesce(u."Unit1", p."id")
from Units as u
    full outer join (select * from price where "rate per" > 0) as p on p."id" = u."Unit1";
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/ef6e5/8)

Comment: it doesn't matter. How will you decide if Price table is empty for row in units?

Comment: please see my requirement